# Updating a scoreboard with a scheduler

Tags: minecraft

I havent added a bukkit runnable because it did not work at all. That is why I added the scoreboard code. No idea how I can update the scoreboard.
IGNORE IGNORE IGNORE IGNORE IGNORE IGNORE IGNORE

SCOREBOARD CODE:

```
public void makeScoreboard() {
    if(this.getConfig().getBoolean("Scoreboard") == true) {
    board = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();

    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Objective objective = board.registerNewObjective("Test", "Test2");
    objective.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "§aMazeRunner §8┃ §c" + StartCountdown.timeUntilStart);
    objective.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

    team = board.registerNewTeam("Team");
    team.setPrefix("");

    Score score2 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§6§l» Time");
    score2.setScore(8);

    Score score3 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§f" + date.format(now));
    score3.setScore(7);

    Score score4 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.RED + " ");
    score4.setScore(6);

    Score score5 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§6§l» Server");
    score5.setScore(5);

    Score score6 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§3EU§8: §f2266");
    score6.setScore(4);

    Score score7 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.RED + "  ");
    score7.setScore(3);

    Score score8 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§6§l» Teams");
    score8.setScore(2);

    Score score9 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§fHumans: 2");
    score9.setScore(1);

    Score score10 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "§fGrievers: 0");
    score10.setScore(0);
    }
    else{

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add complate of ScoreBoard class file to your question

Comment: Here you have it:

Comment: this is not all of your codes. I mean like this link https://gist.github.com/amhokies/7309869

Comment: http://pastebin.com/n4QXNM11 Here it is.

Comment: uh, what is the "IGNORE" in the question for?

Answer (score 1):

To update the scoreboard you can use a [scheduler](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html).

```
BukkitScheduler scheduler = plugin.getServer().getScheduler();

    scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Update your scoreboard ( e.g scoreX.setScore(1); )

        }
                    }, 0L, 20L);
```

This will execute with an initial delay of 0 seconds, repeating itself every 20 ticks = 1 second.

"plugin" is a reference to your class that extends JavaPlugin, you can get an instance of the class using the constructor in case you are executing the code somewhere else, e.g

```
    private Plugin pl;

public SampleListener(Plugin pl) {

    this.pl = pl;

}
```

and then pass "pl" to the scheduler.

Comment: But how and where do I get the score1.setScore etc etc from?

Comment: Instead of defining them within a method you could declare them as private. Also, please use a for loop for creating multiple objects of the same type.